# Stack using linked list in C - Display function does not stop

Tags: c, data-structures

In the below C code that demonstrates the implementation of stack using linked list, calling the display function when the stack has some nodes prints all the nodes but doesn't stop after the last node. It prints the last node again and again. How do I solve this issue? (Compiled using gcc version: gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc()

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *first = NULL, *last = NULL, *temp, *newnode;

struct node * create() {
    newnode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (newnode == NULL) {
        printf("Memory is not allocated\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Enter data: ");
        scanf("%d", &newnode->data);
        newnode->next = NULL;
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = newnode;
        }
        return newnode;
    }
}

void push() {
    newnode = create();
    newnode->next = first;
    first = newnode;
}

void pop() {
    if (first == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty\n");
    } else if (first == last) {
        printf("Deleted node is %d\n", first->data);
        first = last = NULL;
    } else {
        printf("Deleted node is %d\n", first->data);
        first = first->next;
    }
}

void display() {
    if (first == NULL) {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    } else {
        temp = first;
        while(temp != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

void main(void) {
    int choice, flag = 1;
    while(flag) {
        printf("1. Push\n2. Pop\n3. Display\n4. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                push();
                break;
            
            case 2:
                pop();
                break;

            case 3:
                display();
                break;

            case 4:
                flag = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1. Push       
2. Pop        
3. Display    
4. Exit       
Enter choice: 1
Enter data: 52
1. Push
2. Pop
3. Display
4. Exit
Enter choice: 1
Enter data: 24
1. Push
2. Pop
3. Display
4. Exit
Enter choice: 3
24 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 ...
```

Here the output just repeats the data part of the last node again and again.

Comment: You last node will always point to the second element in the list, or to the first, if only 1 exists. Think about which `next` points to what. Probably draw a graph of it.

Comment: You modify your list pointers in `create` and in `push`. This will cause an extra link for the very first node you push to itself.`first = last = newnode;  ... newnode->next = first; first = newnode;` You should not mess with the list while creating a new node. That should only be done in `push`.